# Different Classes, Different Processes

Tags: c#, process

Simply, a console application with three classes as following,

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main ( string [ ] args )
        {
            new Consumer ( );
            new Provider ( );

            Console . WriteLine ( "Exit ..." );
            Console . ReadKey ( );

        }
    }

    public class Consumer
    {
        public Consumer ( )
        {
            using ( Process Process = Process . GetCurrentProcess ( ) )
            {
                Console . WriteLine ( "Consumer : " + Process . ProcessName );
            }
        }
    }

    public class Provider
    {
        public Provider ( )
        {
            using ( Process Process = Process . GetCurrentProcess ( ) )
            {
                Console . WriteLine ( "Provider : " + Process . ProcessName );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output will be as following,

```
Consumer : Stackoverflow.vshost
Provider : Stackoverflow.vshost
Exit ...
```

**Question :**
Can I attach each class to different Process, without separating them into different solutions, especially Provider & Consumer classes ?
It's for testing purposes. Mobile agents related testing.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,

Comment: No. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm doing mobile agents testing and want to see them moving from one process to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will exactly do what you are trying to achieve, but you can load the code into different AppDomain's during execution of the main application.  The following [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173139%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) contains information for doing so with a full example.

From the MSDN [Article on AppDomain's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173138):

> Application domains provide a flexible and secure method of isolating
>   running applications.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is start each class in a different thread.

You can't create a new process "within" the current process.

Answer (score 0):

Run separate processes by defining which *concrete* class has to be executed on program run. 
To defin this you can use simple commandline-arguments. 
So your program reads commandline-argument ande decides which type to run.

like for example:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(args[0] == "consumer") 
          //run consumer 
        else 
          //run provider (as default)

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Input :  
`Stackoverflow.exe c`
Output :
`Consumer : Stackoverflow`
`Exit ...`

Comment: Input :  
`Stackoverflow.exe p`
Output :
`Provider : Stackoverflow`
`Exit ...`

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim: but you check for  "c" and "p". And also I saw that ou print out Process.Name, but the process name is the same for all of them. So may be you can print out the TYPE name, to see the difference.

Answer (score -2):

Simple mistake. You didn't add the `{0}'`. Fixed for you:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Consumer();
        new Provider();

        Console.WriteLine("Exit ...");
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}

public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer()
    {
        using(Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer : {0}", p.ProcessName);
        }
    }
}

public class Provider
{
    public Provider()
    {
        using(Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Provider : {0}", p.ProcessName);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Consumer : SOF
Provider : SOF
Exit ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually forget the + :)